# Execute javascript located in html from a php file on a server

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller, server

I have a form that submits to a php file located on a server. That php file then executes some code as well as a javascript function located in the html. The code worked when I had all the files in the same folder however when uploaded the php file to the server it seems as though it can no longer communicate with the the client side javascript? Does anyone know how to fix this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function updatepicture(pic){
      parent.document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src",pic+"?"+new Date().getTime());
      parent.document.getElementById("path").setAttribute("value",pic);
   }
</script>
```

This is the javascript located in the head of my html

```
?>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                parent.document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";
                //parent.document.getElementById("file").value="";
                window.parent.updatepicture("<?php echo 'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; ?>");
            </script>
<?php
```

This is the code in the php file that I am using to execute that function.

Comment: Hi Warsh, any chance you could post some example code?

Comment: I added a code sample

Comment: try changing `window.parent' in php file to 'parent.document' and check if it works

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. The called to change the inner html in the message tag is also not doing anything